# Data Modeling for consumer goods

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema, data-modeling

A company is trying to build a system that breaks down consumer goods (soft drinks, detergents, beauty products, etc.) down to the very basic components. The aim is to be able to break down all the characteristics of a product into as many enumerable quantities as possible. For instance, a soft drink will have the properties flavor, calories, color, cost, etc. Do note that the products will come from a huge variety of segments and not all properties will be applicable to all products (detergents don't have calories) and similarly sounding properties are not similar (detergents with a lime fragrance is different from a lime flavored soft drink). Also, search is expected to be fast and the database needs to understand relationships between products. Suggest only a data model for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you highlight, that not all properties describe all products, is a classic feature of a class/subclass situation.  Or, if you prefer, type/subtype.

Dealing with just that feature of the problem, I'm going to call your attention to the EER  (Extended Entity Relationship) model if you want to model your understanding of the subject matter.  The EER has a way of depicting what it calls a generalization/specialization pattern.  That's a good search term to find detailed descriptions of it.  This will adequately depict what you've said you're after.

A word of caution, however.  The majority of ER models you'll see here in SO are design models, not conceptual models.  That is, they reflect the intent of designing tables made up of columns and rows, with keys and foreign keys,  to contain the relevant data.

What I'm recommending is the EER model for a very different purpose.  It's to depict the way the data looks to the subject matter expert, not the way the data looks to the database designer.  That distinction is lost on those who have never learned the difference between analysis and design.

If your project is a major one, it's worth spending an appropriate amount of time on a detailed analysis of the subject matter before moving on to design.  Understanding the problem before you try to solve it is key to successful work on big projects.

Once you have a good conceptual model that captures the analysis, the choice of a data model to reflect the design will depend on what kind of database you've decided to build.  It might be relational, it might be multidimensional, it might be unstructured.  It depends.  The analysis, however, will be more useful if it's implementation independent.